# tkinter - resizing empty frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

### How do you force a frame to get window_height 0?

the general case where my problem occurs:

```
import Tkinter as Tk

class App(Tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Tk.Frame(self, master)
        self.place_holder = Tk.Frame(master=self)
        self.content = Tk.Frame(master=self)

        self.place_holder.pack()
        self.content.pack(side=Tk.RIGHT)

        Tk.Button(master=self,command=self.add_something).pack(side=Tk.TOP)
        self.to_destroy = []

    def add_something(self):
        foo = Tk.button(master=self.place_holder, command=self.destroy_last)
        self.too_destroy.append(foo)

    def destroy_last(self):
        self.to_destroy[-1].destroy()
```

### the problem:

As I add more elements to the `place_holder`, it rescales nicely.

When I remove elements from the `place_holder`, it rescales nicely.
**EXCEPT** when I remove the last element.

Before i added anything, even when i do `place_holder.pack()`, it will not show. But after removing the last element, the place_holder will keep the size of this last element. Is there a way to hide the `place_holder` again untill i add content again?

### example image

[image: empty place_holder at bottom left]
The empty container at the bottom left does not contain any elements, but still has the size of the last element in it, how can i get this to disappear without removing it (i want it again in the same place)?

Comment: @stovfl when using `pack_forget()` and `pack()`, the Frame/Widget will be repositioned in as if you `pack()`'ed a new frame. It is not like grid_remove where it remembers the position.

Comment: the real problem i'm trying to solve is to get a frame before an another frame using `pack()` . I've in the meantime discovered the existance of the `before` option for PanedWindow's. Does this option also work for `pack()` ? (it would eliminate the need for the existance of the place_holder)

Comment: @miThom: *"to get a frame before an another frame"*: The [Grid Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) is especially convenient to use when you want to get them all where you want them.

Comment: @stovfl i remember having the same issue with grid as with pack/pack_forget. the empty cell kept it's size upon deletion of the last element inside of it. But i am not sure if i had an empty frame in that cell or not... might be worth testing again

Comment: @miThom: *"not sure if i had an empty frame"*:  Verify with `print('children:{}'.format(self.place_holder.children))`

Comment: @miThom: Workaround, do `self.place_holder.configure(borderwidth=0)` after last `.destroy()`

Comment: There are several small syntax errors that prevent us from being able to run your code.

Comment: i found only 1, fixed it, also added the import to remove confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that when you remove the last widget, `pack` no longer is managing the frame so it isn't responsible for setting the frame size.

The simplest solution is just to temporarily pack a 1x1 pixel frame, which wil cause the placeholder frame to shrink.

There's no way to make a frame of zero pixels, so this method will always result in a one pixel tall/wide area for the placeholder. If you don't want that one pixel, you can install call `pack_forget` on the placeholder to completely remove it from the display, and then use `pack` with suitable options to re-add it when you put something in it.

Example:

```
def destroy_last(self):
    self.to_destroy.pop().destroy()
    if len(self.to_destroy) == 0:
        tmp = Tk.Frame(self.place_holder, width=1, height=1, borderwidth=0)
        tmp.pack()
        self.place_holder.update()
        tmp.destroy()
```

Comment: the fact that it will always stay a 1x1 pixel is a bummer, i don't want that indeed. I missed the fact that the pack manager wasn't available anymore on destruction of last element. This is a good explanation as to why it is impossible to do exactly what i want. I switched to another method to accomplish what i wanted. My answer to people looking for the same: it is impossible, but you can accomplish the same thing in a lot of different ways, so don't get stuck in a thought pattern.